# TypeError: authors.map is not a function at getStaticPaths deploy on Vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, strapi

Hello I've got this error message that I can't find a good solution to

```
16:15:16.470
> Build error occurred
16:15:16.472
TypeError: authors.map is not a function
16:15:16.474
    at getStaticPaths (/vercel/path0/frontend/.next/server/pages/author/[username].js:46:20)
16:15:16.474
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
16:15:16.475
    at async buildStaticPaths (/vercel/path0/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:16:80)
16:15:16.475
    at async /vercel/path0/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:26:622
16:15:16.475
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:6:584) {
16:15:16.475
  type: 'TypeError'
16:15:16.475
}
16:15:16.506
```

As you can tell it is having issues with the render, if anyone could suggest a solution to this code that would be much appreciated

```
const Author = ({ author }) => {
  return (
    <div className="author-page">
      <img src={`https://pacific-sands-66227.herokuapp.com/uploads${author.photo.url}`} />
      <div className="author-details">
        <h1>{author.name}</h1>
        <p className="bio">{author.bio}</p>
        <p>
          @{author.twitter} - {author.website}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL}/authors`);
  const authors = await response.json();
  return {
    paths: authors.map((author) => ({
      params: {
        username: author.username,
      },
    })),
    fallback: 'blocking',
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const response = await fetch(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL}/authors?username=${params.username}`
  );
  const authors = await response.json();

  return {
    props: { author: authors[0] },
    revalidate: 10,
  };
}

export default Author;
```

This seems almost impossible to fix, would i need to convert to a class component?

Comment: The error is very clear, it tells you that `authors` is not an array, what is the output of `console.log(authors)`?

Comment: I just don't think that is the issue, since it works on my local machine, it seems to either be an issue with how it fetches the data or renders the props

https://pacific-sands-66227.herokuapp.com/authors data here

Comment: then I get FetchError: invalid json response body at https://pacific-sands-66227.herokuapp.com/posts reason: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0

Comment: Does it work if you hardcode the Strapi API URL in the code? Is your `NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL` env variable properly set up in Vercel?